# How can I handle click event to Web readonly TextBox in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, event-handling, click

How can I handle click event to Web readonly TextBox in c#

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at  [OnClick Event for Text Box in ASP.NET with C#](http://forums.asp.net/t/1085050.aspx):

> indeed TextBox doesn't have Click
>   event at server-side. One reason is
>   that it wouldn't necessarily be
>   reasonable to cause a postback to
>   clear a TextBox (server-side event
>   requires server-side action to occur
>   e.g also a postback).
>
> But, textBox is a web control which
>   supports expando attributes, that is,
>   any attribute added to the control tag
>   which doesn't match any member of the
>   control, is arendered out as is to the
>   markup. So you could in fact use this
>   to create a javascript click action to
>   clear the TextBox. Either set this on
>   aspx
>
> ```
> <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnClick="this.value=''"/>
> ```
>
> or this in code
>
> ```
> Me.TextBox1.Attributes("onclick") = "this.value=''"
> ```